# Element rotation with point-along-path interpolation - not possible on path with arc?

Tags: d3.js, svg, path

I am working with D3.js in version 3.x.

Following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/c3849a0b15234d7e32fc) tutorial, I am trying to move an element, in this case a rectangle, along a path and rotate the element based on its position on the path.

This works perfectly fine for any path, that **does not have an arc** as part of it. Something like this:

M56.200012207,96.1999969482c-51,295,-52,294,280,184c-286,-273,-243,-261,-35,-204

The angle is calculated "correct" on a path like this, and the element translates along this path in a smooth way.

But as soon as the path contains an arc, the angle gets some strange values at some points of the arc and therefore the rectangle flips / jumps around based on this angle while translating along the path. A path with an arc looks like this for example:

M56.20001220703125,66.19999694824219a174.796117,174.796117,0,1,0,275.99999999996874,-2.000000000042192

**My assumption:**

As for creating an arc, we only give some values, like startpoint and angle, and the rest of the points needed to draw the arc are computed in some way by svg.
Based on my tries, i saw that some of the computed points are not actually where i would expect them to be.

[image: Screenshot_1]

The function used in the linked example calculates two points, p1 and p2 and calculates the angle for the rotation by using Math.atan2 on p1 and p2.
I know the points are very close together, but to simplify my explanation, i have some distance between them in the image.
In this image, i would expect **p1** to have smaller values for x and y than **p2**.
There are a lot of points in that area between p1 and p2, so the function calculates the required angle for each of these pairs. For most of them, the angle is correct, but not for all of them as can be seen in the following console.log() output:

[image: output of p1, p2 and angle]

Notice that for most points, the angle is around 67 degree, which is supposed to be like this on the respective area of the path. But then there randomly is one angle that is 33 degree, which of course causes this flipping / jumping effect.

For "expected angles" the transition looks good and something like this:

[image: working]

For "not expected angles", the transition looks bad and something like this:

[image: not working]

If this happens a few times throughout the transition, this produces the flipping / jumping effect.

**My question:**

Why is this happening? The arc looks fine and all the points seem to be in place based on visually looking at them on screen.
Is there any way to avoid this while still being able to use paths with an arc inside?

Thank you very much for any help.

Edit: Added a jsfiddle to show you the problems discussed here and in the comments: [Element rotation with point-along-path interpolation - not possible on path with arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799741/element-rotation-with-point-along-path-interpolation-not-possible-on-path-with?noredirect=1#comment74723616_43799741)

Comment: Have you got some testing code somewhere ?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE].in your question

Comment: I notice that the dy's (between p1.y and p2.y) are roughly 1.0 for the other points. But for that point it is approx 0.46.  So something is up with your path it seems. Does that location correspond with a new path command or a join perhaps?

Comment: Based on LeBeau's comment above, try to increase the distance between the points, since the greater the distance the less the error: `p2 = path.getPointAtLength((atLength)+direction*2)`, or even `*3` or more.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. 
@PaulLeBeau the path I am using is just any kind of arc, e.g. something like this: <path id="myPath" d="M 50 50 L 200 50 **A** 50 50 0 0 1 200 350 L 50 350" fill="none" style="stroke: #FF0000; stroke-width: 2px;"></path>
The problem is kind of independent from the exact path used, but it appears as soon as an "A" is used to draw an arc.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you are right, things get better if i multiply as you suggested. But instead of *2 or *3, i will have to go with atleast *20 or greater to totally avoid the flipping effect. This though results in that the rectangle changes its angle way too early on very narrow curves. Something like this: http://oi67.tinypic.com/1rdzxi.jpg
In this image, "p2 original" would be used for the angle calculation if i dont use your multiplication. But with multiplication, "p2 new" will be used. So when at "p1", the rect will start to rotate around the curve already.

Comment: At this point, the only way to help you is if you create a (non) working code. It's very difficult to say what's going on here without seeing your code.

Comment: I agree. Meanwhile i was creating a jsfiddle for you guys. Thank you very much again for your help here.

https://jsfiddle.net/42y1d30m/1/

In the jsfiddle, you can follow one of the two paths by replacing the argument of the translateRotateAlong method with either "myRegularPath" or "myArcPath".

Also you will see that i introduced a "smoothFactor", which is the multiplication you suggested.
With smoothFactor of 50, i can perfectly follow the "myArcPath", but for "myRegularPath" it looks weird.
Without the smoothFactor, "myRegularPath" is perfect, but "myArcPath" has flipping effect.

Comment: Interesting. It works fine (for both paths) in Firefox, but you get the bad behaviour in Chrome for the path with the Arc commands. Looks like it is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using Chrome. But it seems you found out already ;-) So you think there is nothing I can do about it?

Comment: It definitely does seem to be a Chrome bug. I've reported it to the Chrome bug tracker. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719516

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do other than trying to smooth the values (either by extending your distance as you are doing, or averaging multiple adjacent values). Or by avoiding arc commands in your paths.

Comment: For instance, here's an example where we average the nearby tangents to produce results that a more accurate: https://jsfiddle.net/42y1d30m/5/  Compare with original: https://jsfiddle.net/42y1d30m/3/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks for your input. Sadly I can not avoid using arc commands, so meanwhile i will try to smooth the values based on your latest comment. You really helped me out here. If you guys want to append you information into an answer, i would mark that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in current Chrome (57 and 58 as of writing) that affects the return values for `getPointAtLength()` when operating on arc path commands.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719516

For now there seems to be no easy fix other than smoothing the output values yourself.  Or avoiding arc commands in your paths.